# Natural Language Processing: Basic Dimension Reduction with SVD of a Co-Occurence Matrix

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, natural-language

Given sentences

1. I enjoy flying.
2. I like NLP.
3. I like deep learning

We can form a Co-Occurrence Matrix as follows:[image]

Now we can apply Singular Value Decomposition to this matrix to get
$X = U \Sigma V^T$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal and $\Sigma$ is diagonal and the singular values are sorted (I believe) so $\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq \ldots \geq \sigma_r$.

My question is what do the matrices $U$, $\Sigma$, $V$ represent in terms of the words and/or sentences and the relationship between words.

If I think about matrices as linear transformations essentially SVD is taking some matrix $X$ and decomposing it into a (rotation)(stretch)(rotation).

I am ultimately looking for a way to think about the SVD decomposition of a co-occurrence matrix more intuitively.

Comment: Welcome to the CV community. I tried to show you the interpretation of the document-by-term matrix because it is much more general from the co-occurrence matrix while encapsulating very similar information.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the co-occurrence matrix is not very relevant for an NLP application as the information it includes is readily available in the term-by-document count matrix.

Through the analysis of the document-by-term matrix what we would be describing would be a prototypical application of [Latent Semantic Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) (LSA) (some people refer to LSA as Latent Semantic Index (LSI) - it is the same thing). The original reference for LSA is Deerwester et al. (1990) ["*Indexing by latent semantic analysis*"](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~pxt/IDA/lsa_ind.pdf) and it pretty much the application of  PCA to a term by document count matrix. Usually one does not use the raw count but some transformed count through [TFIDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) (term frequency-inverse document frequency) but the idea remains the same.

In short, we can think of the $U$, $\Sigma$ and $V$ representing a "document-to-concept", a "power-of-concept" and a "term-to-concept" (assuming an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ with $m$ documents and $n$ terms) respectively.

Co-occurrence matrices can be very helpful for image analysis (e.g. see Clausi (2002) ["*An analysis of co-occurrence texture statistics as a function of grey level quantization*"](http://www.eng.uwaterloo.ca/~dclausi/Papers/Published%202002/Clausi%20-%20GLCP%20and%20quantization%20-%20CJRS%202002.pdf) as they can be used to encapsulate texture statistics but that is because texture does not have the same interpretation as actual word-terms. (I  recall seeing co-occurance data being used a metric for the purposes of MDS but again for an NLP we might as well use the term-by-document counts matrix to get the same info.)